# How to speed up pixel rendering in LWJGL?

Tags: performance, lwjgl, pixel, frame-rate, cpu-speed

I was just trying out different ways of rendering with LWJGL. I came across this method `glDrawPixels(width, height, format, type, bytebuffer)`.
So with this method I decided to try rendering just pixels in LWJGL and came up with this:

```
package biz.boulter.pixTest;

import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Game
{
    private static long secTimer;
    private static int ticks = 0;
    private static int frames = 0;

    private static ByteBuffer buffer;

    public static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private static long lastFrame;
    public static int[] pixels = new int[WIDTH * HEIGHT];

    private static void tick()
    {

    }

    private static void render()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            {
                int color = pixels[y * WIDTH + x];

                buffer.put((byte) ((color >> 16) & 0xFF));
                buffer.put((byte) ((color >> 8) & 0xFF));
                buffer.put((byte) ((color) & 0xFF));
                buffer.put((byte) ((color >> 24) & 0xFF));
            }
        }

        buffer.flip();

        glDrawPixels(WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    }

    public static int getDelta()
    {
        long now = getTime();
        int delta = (int) (now - lastFrame);
        lastFrame = now;
        return delta;
    }

    public static long getTime()
    {
        return (Sys.getTime() * 100) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }

    public static long getMilliTime()
    {
        return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create();
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        getDelta();
        secTimer = getMilliTime();
        buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer((WIDTH * HEIGHT) * 4);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            int delta = getDelta();

            while (delta >= 1)
            {
                tick();
                ticks++;
                delta--;
            }

            render();
            frames++;

            if (getMilliTime() - secTimer >= 1000)
            {
                System.out.println(frames + " fps\t" + ticks + " ups");
                ticks = 0;
                frames = 0;
                secTimer += 1000;
            }

            Display.update();
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly however I noticed that the fps was about 500 frames less then when I use the normal LWJGL matrix mode rendering. So how can I speed it up so i don't have to loop through the pixels and add the RGBA values to a byte buffer every single frame?

Comment: Why do you want to use drawPixels instead of the normal matrix mode rendering which is faster in most cases?

Comment: Just interested. LWJGL must do it with pixels, so there must be a way to do this just as fast.

Comment: Well, have you looked into what lines exactly cause the FPS drop?

Comment: well its putting all four RGBA values into the byte buffer for every pixel and it takes a while for it to complete the loop.